# Calculate altitude using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I want to calculate altitude of a marker but I didn't find any solution in Leaflet. I found the elevation plugin which allow to draw elevation profil on map, but I don't need that. Do you have idea how to calculate altitude? Thank you.

Comment: Leaflet is a 2D JavaScript mapping library without any content/data - what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Altitude on a marker is a piece of data like lat or long  , not really something you would calculate...

Comment: I want to get altitude of marker exactly like lng and lat

Comment: @nermiiine Where do you get your marker's lat and lng from? Sounds like it should be where you get your altitude as well. If not, look for another source to get that data from. Leaflet is like the rendering engine, not the data source.

Comment: I'm using leaflet draw plugin to draw my marker, so I got lat and lng using this function **getLatLng**

Comment: Leaflet draw has no idea whatsoever of the altitude of the basemap area on which you are drawing on top of.

Comment: Oki I understood, so what I have to do?

Comment: Find a datasource/api that you can tap which accepts lat/long coordinates and responds with altitude?

Comment: But I want to add another datasource without changing Leaflet.

Comment: You don't need to change Leaflet's code, you are augmenting leaflet's behavior with a external datasource.

Comment: oki good, but I can't find any external api that contain information about altitude.

Comment: Still can't find solution.

Answer (score 6):

### Edit: A nice option

Adding this for anyone who might want it: since having written this answer, I wrote the plugin [**leaflet-topography**](https://github.com/slutske22/leaflet-topography) to make doing this very fast and easy.

### Original answer:

Not sure if anyone has answered yet but I cracked my head over this for a week and found a nice solution.  First, you need to get the leaflet plugin leaflet-tileLayer-colorPicker:

https://github.com/frogcat/leaflet-tilelayer-colorpicker

This plugin enables you to get the color of a certain pixel on the map, given the latitude and longitude.  Then, you need a dataset.  One that's designed for this is the mapbox Terrain-RGB tiles:

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/

These tiles have elevation data encoded in RGB format.  The description on mapbox's site was not step-by-step enough for a beginner like me, so here's how you can do it:

**Add the Terrain-RGB tilelayer**

```js
var colorPicker = L.tileLayer.colorPicker('https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.terrain-rgb/{z}/{x}/{y}.pngraw?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.outdoors',
  accessToken: 'your mapbox accesstoken'
  }).addTo(yourMap)
  .setOpacity(0); // optional
```

**Create a function which takes in latlng and outputs RGB as an array**

```
function getElevation(location){
var color = colorPicker.getColor(location)
// location is an array [lat, lng]
```

Pick apart the RGB values of the array and put into mapbox's elevation equation

```
   let R = color[0];
   let G = color[1];
   let B = color[2];

   let height = -10000 + ((R * 256 * 256 + G * 256 + B) * 0.1)
   let heightRounded = Math.round( height * 10) / 10 + ' meters';
   return heightRounded;
}
```

That last bit is just to give a nice number rounded to the first decimal, output as a string like "182 meters", but you can write it however you like.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem working on a Shiny app with leaflet and found a workaround using [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start) and `google_elevation()` function of [googleway package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/googleway.pdf)

The latter (R part) is probably not in your interest but the Google Elevation API implementation should work for you.